# Python/Django returning empty queryset

Tags: python, django

I display a table of matches in one of my views. Now the view gets data from the queryset in the function `get_next_match()`. Problem is, it keeps giving an error that the queryset is `None`.

What is the best way to catch this, so that it does not error the page, but just displays/prints something like "There is no data".

This is the function:

```
try:
    return Match.objects.filter(team_filter).filter(
        match_date__gt=current_match.match_date).order_by('match_date').first()
except Match.DoesNotExist:
    return Match.objects.none()
```

The Exception:
Exception Value:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'match_date'
```

Comment: You return in the except, but not in the try. Where do you return the query results? Please show the full code and the full traceback.

Comment: You're right, the original code was return Match.objects.filter(.........), this was from some testing. It's still erroring at the line `match_date__gt ....`

Comment: OK so the error is because `current_match` is None. Well, you should check for that first.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the try/except. You can check if the queryset is empty before trying to access the first item from it. If you're testing a queryset in a boolean context such as an `if` statement it will return `True` if there is at least 1 result or `False` if the queryset is empty.

```
matches = Match.objects.filter(team_filter)\
                       .filter(match_date__gt=current_match.match_date)\
                       .order_by('match_date')

return matches.first() if matches else None
```

Also if you're only going to be using only the first item in the queryset remember to [limit the query to 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) as it will be much more efficent

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already found out what the problem was. In a different function it was filtering the match date on timezone. Since there was no current match for that time, it was returning `None` :/ thanks though